# Is "treehouse" one word or two?

Tags: word-usage

Is **treehouse** one word or two?

Would you say, "I built a **treehouse**?" Or "I built a **tree house**?"

Comment: It is "use it as you please" word. Would you say "war horse" or "warhorse"?

Comment: was going to close as "dictionary question",  but the major dictionaries don't seem to reflect reality here.

Comment: Have you checked any dictionaries?

Comment: Here's a hint: can you see a space in 'treehouse'?

Comment: One word. It's no different to "handbag", "broomstick", "birdcage" and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Treehouse" of "tree house" is a compound word.  It is [generally spelled](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22tree%20house%22%2Ctreehouse&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) as a single word with no space, but there is some variation, especially in Britain

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tree-house) dictionary prefers the form with a space,

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/treehouse) prefers the form without a space, but notes the form with a space as a British variant.

Comment: If it's written as two words i.e. tree house", it can hardly be a compound noun, now can it? Compounds by definition are single words. "Treehouse" (or "tree-house) is a compound noun, but "tree house" is a syntactic construction consisting of head (house) and modifier ("tree").

Comment: Actially I don't feel like being lectured by you.  See Cambridge Dictionary and go argue with them.

Comment: See CGEL, the finest grammar ever written, whose lead author Rodney Huddleston, is the finest grammarian of the English language alive today.

Comment: @BillJ: This cannot possibly be what CGEL says.  See [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/525003/how-is-compound-noun-defined-in-cgel), which says that *full stop* is classified as a compound noun; *fullstop* is almost always written as two words.

Answer (score 1):

'Treehouse' (one word) and 'tree house' (two words) are both possible.

I would use **Tree house**.

tree house= a structure built in the branches of a tree

two words➜ monkey house, lion house, hen house, dog house, brick house, fashion house, publishing house,

Comment: Why would you say "tree house" but "greenhouse"?

Comment: BillJ, 
Because green cannot be parted from greenhouse.

Comment: And "tree" cannot be parted from "house", so what's the difference? [link](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/treehouse)

Comment: It's true that many people do write it as two words, but syntactically it's a compound noun.

Comment: Yes, It's a compound noun. Compound nouns can be written as two words. Examples- bottle opener, car park, tree house, bus stop, Prime Minister, town square, small talk, full moon, hot dog

Comment: [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/hotdog) Your other examples fail the tests. See my answer.

Comment: And proper nouns like "Prime Minister" are special cases. We're talking here of common nouns.

Answer (score -3):

> *I built a treehouse / tree house*

I don't think there's any doubt that it's a compound noun, and therefore it should be written as a single word, possibly hyphenated as "tree-house".

If it's written as two words i.e. tree house", it would be a syntactic construction consisting of head ("house") and modifier ("tree").

Syntactically, it qualifies as a compound by virtue of passing the tests for compoundhood.

For example, the component parts cannot be modified: if we say "a big tree house", the modifier "big" refers to the tree house as a whole, not just the tree.

And the components can't separately enter into a coordination: "a tree and wooden house" makes little sense.

Compare words like "greenhouse", "birdcage", "ashtray" and the like. We don't want to call them syntactic constructions and write them as "green house", "bird cage" and "ash tray". They are compound nouns that should be written as single words.

These dictionaries gets it right:

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/treehouse

https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/treehouse

Comment: This logic doesn't hold water. There are lots of things that behave like compound nouns that are generally written as single words. For example, *stock car*, *swimming pool*, and *ice cream*. You can't say *a deep and swimming pool* or *a delicious and ice cream*, it has to be *a deep swimming pool* and *a delicious ice cream.*

Comment: If you want to use your own private variety of English and spell stock-car, ice-cream, and swimming-pool with hyphens, that's your prerogative. But let me point out that even the dictionary you claim "gets it right" spells [stock car](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stock-car), [swimming pool](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/swimming-pool), and [ice cream](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ice-cream) as two words. I agree they're compound nouns, but in traditional English, there is no requirement to spell compound nouns as one word.

Comment: If they are compound nouns, then it makes no sense to write them as two separate words. Where's the logic in that? "Ice-cream" and "swimming-pool" are written as single words to distinguish them from syntactic constructions Btw, [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/ice-cream) / And Collins also mentions it as "ice-cream". Btw, you should delete your first comment, as it was based on a false premise.

Comment: Where is the logic in any English spelling?

Comment: You are 100% wrong when you say that in traditional English, there is no requirement to spell compound nouns as one word. It **is** necessary to distinguish cases where two bases combine to form a single word, a compound, from those where they constitute separate words in a syntactic construction. For example "greenhouse" a morphological compound vs "green house", a syntactic construction.